# Google Glass GDK view error, sad cloud TableView

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have a simple glass application Live Card which displays fine when debugging on Google Glass, however if I add a TableLayout (with or without rows) and debug on glass, I get the sad cloud.  The card uses no  dependent resources like network connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/live-cards#creating_low-frequency_live_cards), `TableLayout` is not one of the types of views/widgets that are supported by `RemoteViews`. (This is a restriction in the Android framework and not Glass-specific.) Whenever `RemoteViews` fail to inflate properly, it is manifested as this "sad cloud" image.

You may want to consider redesigning your layout to use nested `LinearLayout`s instead in order to get around this restriction.